# Using EntityManager on top of Spring Data Repositories

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

Recently, I came across the following piece of code:

```
@Transactional
public MyEntity insert(MyEntity entity) {
    MyEntity merged = entityManager.merge(entity);
    return myEntityRepository.save(merged);
}
```

where entity manager is defined as follows:

```
@PersistenceContext private EntityManager entityManager;
```

and repository is Spring QueryDSL repository:

```
@Repository
public interface MyEntityRepository extends QueryDslRepository<MyEntity>{
}
```

My question is, whether is it really necessary to call `entityManager.merge(entity)` when we are persisting the entity using the `myEntityRepository` right after? Is there something the entityManager is doing that the repository cannot? Shouldn't calling the repository be enough?

Comment: It shouldn't be used. The repository does that work if required: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38894500/1199132

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like cargo cult programming to me. The [implementation of `save()`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java#L481) already does a merge if necessary (and sometimes when it isn't necessary):

```
/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository#save(java.lang.Object)
 */
@Transactional
public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {

    if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
        em.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    } else {
        return em.merge(entity);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work when the inserted entity contains some nested entities that need to be updated as well?

Comment: Not sure, what you mean by "it" nor, by "work". The intended behavior of `merge` is described in the JPA spec.

Answer (score 0):

As for me this looks as a pretty dangerous code with a bit blurry intention and some over-engineering:

1. Do you have 100% guarantee to share the same transaction manager between your layer and repository? If not you are in trouble.
2. You are doing just double work (@Jens answer shows it).
3. `@Transactional` here can only make things worse (if you have some non-standard flushing policy). Especially pay attention it will not work if you call method from within the same class as it works via proxy.
4. If you really intend to `insert()` (new record) why do you need `merge()` at all?

My vote is - just use `save()` as @Jens pointed. If you really need `insert()` functionality then you may need real transaction with protection from update and in this case I'd do some custom code on repository layer. Hope you do not need it.