# Spring JPA CrudRepository save(Entity) is returning 0 in id field

Tags: spring, hibernate, db2, spring-data-jpa

I am adding spring JPA/Hibernate 5 to an old project. I am running `CrudRepository .save(Entity)` method against a `Mainframe/DB2` table. The row is inserted just fine, but `returnedEntity.getIdColumn()` has `0` in it. I really need the ID for further processing. Could somebody please help? Thank you very much!

```
@Entity
Table(name="MY_TABLE")
public class myClass {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="ID_COLUMN")
private Long idColumn;
...
```

}

Identity is the only strategy type that worked.
Here is the Service class:

```
@Transactional
public Entiry insertEntity(Entity originalEntity) {
   return MyRepository.save(originalEntity);
}
Runner class:
Entity originalEntity = createEntity();
Entity returnedEntity = ServiceClass.insertEntity(originalEntity);
System.out.println(originalEntity.getIdColumn());
System.out.println(returnedEntity.getIdColumn());
```

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you're trying to get an ID before your transaction was flushed to DB. Thus JPA doesn't know what id will be assigned and returns 0.

**Edited**:
I'd recommend to have something like this:

```
@Transactional
public Entity save( .....) {
   //some code
   repository.save(entity);
   //some code
   return entity;
}
```

Transaction will be flushed at the end of this method and entity which will be returned from it should have a real id.

Comment: Thank you, Andrew. saveAndFlush() of JpaRepository did not help. Is there another way?

Comment: you're welcome) Is the method where you call save transactional?

Comment: If it's transactional - data from hibernate session may not be flushed to DB till the end of this method.

Comment: OK, I removed @Transactional and still having no luck. Do I have any options how to get the Id, or my efforts are doomed? :( Thank you

Comment: So, I tried exactly how you have it, but still got 0. Your version sounds like I would return the original Entity in hope JPA will update it. All other posts suggest that JPA returns a new, updated object. So, I added my version of the code above with interrogating the original Entity object as well as the returned one. Both return 0

Comment: hm...interesting. What about Runner class, is the method which call insertEntity also Transactional? If yes, please add propagation level REQUIRES_NEW for the insertEntity method: @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)

Comment: For some reason it is complaining about propagation saying Cannot resolve method 'propagation'. Thank you

Comment: hm.. Do you mean inside the annotation or what do you mean by method 'propagation' ?

Comment: Turns out I was using the wrong Transactinal. I switched to javax.persistance... and the error went away. The 0 returned value issue remains. From spring debug messages it looks like the transaction is commited before I Sysout it. So, I do not think it is my issue. For some reason DB2 does not return the true value. Somebody suggested using @Query, but it does not look it supports Insert. I am really stuck. :(

Answer (score 2):

Turned out my table had an id sequence generator already defined in the DB. So, after I changed it to generationType.SEQUENCE it worked nicely.
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "MY_TABLE_SEQ")

Answer (score 1):

Recently, I've faced with similar issue.

In my case, the new entity has been passed from UI and **ID was 0 instead of NULL** (since the type of ID was primitive on Java side). Therefore Hibernate didn't use right `save` strategy.

Eventually, I changed the type from `long` to `Long` and it helped:
`private long id;`
`private Long id;`

Also `update` method was changed from:

```
@PutMapping("/{id}")
public T update(@PathVariable ID id, @Valid @RequestBody T entity) {
    this.getService().update(entity);
    return entity;
}
```

to:

```
@PutMapping("/{id}")
public T update(@PathVariable ID id, @Valid @RequestBody T entity) {
    return this.getService().update(entity);
}
```

P.S.: When entity ID was 0, Hibernate was using `merge` strategy, however, it should `persist` strategy for new Entities instead ([link for implementation of **`save`** method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38894500/4567218)).